how to prove $\forall a_n \in \mathbb{R}, n\in \mathbb{N} \exists x \in \mathbb{R} : \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \left( x^k-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)=0 $?
I tried to prove that $\forall a_n \in \mathbb{R} , n\in \mathbb{N}$ then there exist a real root $x$ such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \left( x^k-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)=0 $$
for example if $n=2$ and $a_1=1 , a_2=3$ then
$$ \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right)+3\left( x^2-\frac{1}{3} \right)=0 $$
then
$$ 3x^2+x-\frac{3}{2}=0 \to x=\frac{-1\mp\sqrt{19}}{6}\in \mathbb{R}$$
its easy to prove it for $n=2$ for all values of $a_n$ but I have no idea for $n\ge 3$
and if we prove it can we use it to test if an equation has real root or not ?

Let $p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^k$. Then the equation is equivalent to
$$ p(x) = \int_{0}^{1} p(t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$
Then the conclusion is almost immediate from the mean value theorem for integrals, which tells:

Theorem. Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that the "average value" of $f$ over $[a, b]$ is equal to $f(c)$, that is,
$$ \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(c). $$


nice idea thanks! but I didnt understand  firstly $\int_0^1 p(t) dt=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k+1} \ne p(x) $ and also we proved there exists $c \in (a,b)$ but is it $f(c)=0$ ?

@Faoler, I mean, we have the following identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\left(x^k-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=p(x)-\int_{0}^{1}p(t),\mathrm{d}t, $$ hence finding the zero of the left-hand side of your equation is equivalent to solving the equation (not identity) in my answer.

This can be rewritten as:
$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} x^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_{k}}{k+1} .
$
This function, is a polynomial  (since $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} x^{k} $ is a polynomial) minus a constant term $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_{k}}{k+1} $.
Now analyzing the Behavior of f(x)
Polynomial Behavior: they are continuous and differentiable functions.
Additionally, the behavior of a polynomial at $ \pm \infty $ is dominated by its highest degree term (assuming $ a_{n} \neq 0 $ for the highest degree n .
We also examine the behavior of f(x) as x approaches $ +\infty $ and $ -\infty $ :

As $ x \rightarrow+\infty $, if n is even and $a_{n}>0 $ or n is odd and $ a_{n}>0 $, then $ f(x) \rightarrow+\infty $.
As $ x \rightarrow-\infty $, if n is even and $ a_{n}>0 $ or n is odd and $ a_{n}<0 $, then $ f(x) \rightarrow-\infty $ (and vice versa for $ \left.a_{n}<0\right) $
Now from Intermediate Value Theorem, since f(x) is continuous, if it takes on values of opposite signs at two points (which it does due to the behavior at $ \pm \infty $ ), so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists at least one x  in between where f(x)=0 .

